# (Mac)VIM disable NerdTREE for new and single files

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I have configured NerdTree to open up when i start VIM by using Pathogen and placing NERDTree in my `.vim/bundle` directory. I have installed NERDTreeTabs the same way.

I don't want NERDTree to open though, when i am either opening a single file or creating a new file. How can i do this?

Comment: Why don't you show us how you configured it to open automatically?

Comment: See my edit, no config at all. Just including it via pathogen.

Answer (score 2):

The general "always open NERDTree" behavior is added by NERDTreeTabs, and you can disable it by adding the following line to your `.gvimrc` file:

```
let g:nerdtree_tabs_open_on_gui_startup = 0
```

(There's also an equivalent option for console startup, but it already defaults to 0.)

Then, from the [NERDTree README](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree):

> Q. How can I open a NERDTree automatically when vim starts up if no files were specified?
>
> A. Stick this in your vimrc
>
> autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in=1
>      autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 0 && !exists("s:std_in") | NERDTree | endif

Note: This may not be a 100% perfect solution-- for example, new tabs will be opened without a NERDTree window.  It might be possible to fix that by replacing the `NerdTree` with `NERDTreeTabsToggle` above, but doing that causes vim to show an error about trailing characters, and I don't know why that is.